# how to draw uiprogressview into UIView subclass?

Tags: iphone, sdk, progress-bar, cell, tableview

i can draw a string/image... with drawInRect/drawAtPoint.
but how about if i want to add a UIProgressView into this view?

I am overriding the drawRect method,

so i have to create the UIProgressView inside drawRect?

---

UPDATED BELOW:

Here is my UITableViewCell subclass for another class(just for showing how i did the tableViewCell subclassing) for **Krumelur**, I am not sure if this is correct, but this is how i usually do it.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f,5.0f,40.0f,40.0f)];
//imageView.tag = kImage;
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self.contentView addSubview:imageView];



nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55.0f, 5.0f, 220.0f, 18.0f)];
//nameLabel.tag = kName;
nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
nameLabel.textColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:18.0/255.0 green:18.0/255.0 blue:18.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    //nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
//[nameLabel release];


    statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55.0f, 27.0f, 220.0f, 20.0f)];
//lastMessageLabel.tag = kName;
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:82.0/255.0
                                            green:82.0/255.0
                                             blue:82.0/255.0
                                            alpha:0.8];;
statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:statusLabel];
//[lastMessageLabel release];
}

return self;
```

}

here is how i use it in -(void)cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RootViewTableCell";

RootViewTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[RootViewTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

//cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = TABLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

User *user = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = user.name;
cell.statusLabel.text = user.status;

if (user.photo != nil)
{
    //myUser.photo = user.photo;
    cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
} 
else{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person_default"];
}
return cell;
```

do i have to use a tag for each of the subview? i don't see any difference if i don't.
do you see anything that is causing the tableview scrolling lag? because I use the same thing for my tableview before. the table datasource is from core data, and NSFetchedResultsController for any insert/delete/update, but i am sure that i store the data into a NSMutableArray as datasource, so when i scroll the tableview, there is no core data access(but still laggy). Please if you have any suggestion, i would love to hear, and i love this way more than doing UIView subclassing then override the drawRect.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not draw UIProgressView in a UITableViewCell. The reason why you gain performance by overriding a UITableViewCell's drawRect is because the device only has to composite the first frame of scrolling. The rest of the time, it's a single opaque texture.

Now you know why you gain performance, you can see that you can't draw UIProgressView into drawRect, because you're going to be updating that UIProgressView, which results in slow performance. The drawRect method is only for static content and not meant for cells that have animation.

The best thing to do is to addSubview, but don't add the UIProgressView as a subview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This will result in a lot of duplicate UIProgressViews overlapping each other (due to the cell reuse).

What you want to do is (since you're already subclassing UITableViewCell) create a UIProgressView property in the UITableViewCell subclass, add it to the cell in the initWithStyle method, then rearrange it in the layoutSubviews.

Comment: i tried your solution, but it doesn't work or i don't fully understand it. i create a UIProgressView property in my UITableViewCell subclass, then init the progressView and add it to the cell: [self.contentView addSubview:progressView], i also set the progressView hidden=YES by default, then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, based on some condition, i set the cell.progressView.hidden=NO, and pass it the progress value: cell.progressView.progress = progressValue but when i reload the app, i don't see any progressView. could you please provide me a bit more detail? thanks

Comment: Did you make sure to initialize the progress view and set an appropriate frame?

Comment: you are right, that's my bad, i got the frame wrong (copy&paste issue). now i got it right. i added the uiprogressview in the UITableViewCell as a subview. so now i got two subviews inside UITableViewCell subclass. 1.UIProgressView, 2. UIView(contains all other NSString based content). There is still a small problem. Lets say there are 10 cells already, when i do a background operation, a new progressView is added into the last cell, and i scroll the table view down then up, i can see another exact same progressView running at the first cell. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `drawRect` method is overridden to perform custom drawing in a view. You should not override this method unless you do custom drawing, because doing so hurts performance.

To display an image, consider using an `UIImageView`. To display a `UIProgressView`, add it as a subview, like this:

```
- (void) didMoveToSuperview {
    if(progressView != nil) {
        progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self addSubview:progressView];
    }
}
```

Comment: i used to add subview into table cell, but when i have more than 20-30 rows, the scrolling gets laggy, so that's why i overirde drawRect, and now it scroll very smooth. but i am stucked at adding a UIProgressView.

Comment: Have you properly used the `reuseIdentifier` of the `UITableView`? I do not think that using subviews in a cell should in any way result in scrolling becoming laggy unless something is wrong. Can you show some of the code?

Comment: sorry, i would love to share the code if i still have it, i already removed the old code, and switched to subclassing UIView.

Comment: Still, even if you are subclassing `UIView`, you still need to add the `UIProgressView` during the initialization of the view, not in `drawRect`. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: please if you can, could you please take a look at my updated question? i would love to correct any mistake because i like adding subviews into UITableViewCell more than doing drawRect.